# pyqt4 run a funtion unit the button is holded

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am making a gui in pyqt4 which will enable a function until a button is hold on. The button runs a function. Though when I hold off the button the the function execution stopped. My code is someting like below:

```
 self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func)

 def func(self):
     GPIO.output(StepPinForward, GPIO.HIGH)
     print "forwarding running  motor "
     time.sleep(1)
     GPIO.output(StepPinForward, GPIO.LOW)
```

How to make the function enable until I hold on the button

Comment: Do you want the task to be performed while the button is pressed?

Comment: yeah,I want the task while the button is pressed

Comment: You could give an example of "do something"

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, my fucntion is a bit long but you you could think of it as a simple function.

Comment: Give me that example of a simple function.

Comment: I mean the content of the function. The solution depends on how you implement the function.

Comment: Do you want the pin to be high while the button is pressed and then set to low?

Comment: My actual code exceeds the letter length but it is gpio code for stepper motor and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: all I want is to run the sequence of stepper motor while I press the button

Comment: It's that I need to know that sequence, I think it can be modified to work in a simple way.

Comment: Your code is similar to the following: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-10-stepper-motors/software

Comment: yeah, I told that the code is very long but my code is something like that.The thing is I code it for L297 stepper motor controller. The sequence is 40 steps rotate clockwise wait for 5 s and then return again to its place, and again 30 steps rotate anticlockwise, and wait for 5 s. And again 13 steps clock wise and waiit 5 s , at last come to the starting point. And this step has to repeat while I press the button.

Comment: I think if I could give continuous true signal from button press I can run the function continuously

Comment: Are you using this: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-PI-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Motor/  with the sequence you say? If so, the most robust solution is to implement a state machine.

Comment: The problem is that sleep is blocking and is not friendly with the GUI

Comment: nope I am using one of these http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/f9/35/6e/3f/48/18/48/51/CD00000063.pdf/files/CD00000063.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000063.pdf to control the stepper motor.

Comment: Please share the code to help you, you could do it through drive, github or similar.

Comment: if there is a way to get a signal from button while the button is pressed then I can give a signal to my function whether to continue the sequence or not.

Comment: The problem is to sleep in your code, even if you pass the stop signal, it will not do so until you finish a sleep, or until the but, you end the loop that occurs in 15 seconds. Do you want that behavior?

Comment: yes, it took almost 20s to complete a cycle. I want it and I want to hold on it for at least 40 s for two cycle.

Comment: code is kinda unavailable for me right now, i will share it with you later.

Comment: You should not use sleep inside the GUI for a long time as it will freeze the application, unless you use threads, but I think it is unnecessary in your case.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait for your code, thanks :P